# transaction time between the last past 12 months

Tags: sql

I need results from transaction time between the last past 12 months from the transaction today. example 2018-10-1 to 2019-09-30. who are make the transaction between in this date. But the result return is empty.

```
select  CMM.membership_id, person_birthdayMonth, transaction_time
from cognetic_core_person
where 
transaction_time = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) and DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-12, 0) >= transaction_time and DATENAME(month,GETDATE()) = CCP.person_birthdayMonth
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select CMM.membership_id, person_birthdayMonth, transaction_time
from cognetic_core_person
where transaction_time >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) AND
      transaction_time < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) AND
      DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) = CCP.person_birthdayMonth;
```